# Question about application of Erdős-Kac theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, probability-distributions, prime-numbers

My question is whether (*) below can be shown using the Erdős-Kac theorem? I don't think the distinction between $\Omega$ and $\omega$ is important here.

For lack of better notation let $\lambda_{r,s}(i) := 1$ if $ \Omega(i)\equiv s~ \text{(mod r)}$ and zero otherwise.  For $ (0\leq s,\hat{s}< r)$ and $s\neq \hat{s},$

> $$(*)\hspace{15mm} \sum_{i\leq n} \lambda_{r,s}(i) \sim \sum_{i\leq n} \lambda_{r,\hat{s}}(i)  $$

Briefly the E-K theorem says that

$$\frac{\omega(n)-\log\log n}{\sqrt{\log\log n}}$$

is normally distributed. So the idea would be that for large n the area under the gaussian curve can be divided into bands (mod $r$) and the sums of areas for each $s ~\text{(mod r)}$ are roughly equal, with the caveat that for $r > 2$ the numbers have to be very large for this to work.

For $r = 3,~ n = 2^{22}$ we already have for $s \equiv 0,2,1,$

$\sum_i \lambda_{3,0}(i)/n = 0.3320,$

$\sum_i \lambda_{3,2}(i)/n = 0.3505, $

$\sum_i \lambda_{3,1}(i)/n = 0.3174,  $

Note also: $r$ is fixed as n grows.

Comment: I have found a paper that sort of vindicates the notation in this question and proves a weak version of the proposition in this question. On the Residue Class Distribution of the Number of Prime Divisors of an Integer. Coons and Dahmen, Nagoya Math j. 202, 2011, 15-22.